# MySQL database storing of unknown number of values

Tags: java, mysql

I'm new to MySQL and I'm trying to create a database using Netbeans.
I want to store into this database a name (i. e. string) and then an unspecified number of integers (I don't know in advance, how much would it be).

The only solution I've found so far is to write values of these integers into one string with a specified delimiter. Is there some kind of better approach to this problem (some kind of inflatable arrays or anything similar)?

I'm planning to use this database in Java program.

Comment: will these numbers be filtered, queried in part or in full in any way now or in the future?  If so, normalize the data don't just stuff it into 1 field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add multiple entries for the same name.

```
Name   Number
------------
Test   1
Test   3
Test   5
Other  2
...
```

Then select all entries for that name when you read from it.

Comment: Good normal form use.  and allows filter on entries easier.

Comment: What if I needed to add another collumn? Do I have to repeat its content in every line with this approach?

Comment: In those cases you might want to create a second table containing "name - other column" pairs. Then do a join on them when you want to read all at once ;)

Comment: @E.Brown Using first normal form is usually not a good solution, even if it does solve your immediate problem.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to normalize the data:

**Table name**

```
id   name
------------------
 0   Foo
 1   Bar
```

**Table numbers**

```
id   nameId number
------------------
 0   0      1
 1   0      5
 2   0      17
 3   1      256
```

Each entry in **name** having 0..n entries in table **numbers**. The id-columns might not be necessary depending on other requirements of your application. This might lead to a design as suggested by Mr. M.

Comment: It's a good idea to get accustomed to having an id column, even if it's synthetic. Of course you can learn it the hard way, if that's your thing.